# Find command works from command line but not in a script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I am working on a process that needs to run every night and will tar.gz a large list of files (too large to do with the tar command). To workaround this, I can create a list of files I want tar to archive and pass it in. I usually do this manually, but I'd like to automate it using a crontab.

The OS in this case is RedHat Enterprise 6.3 (Santiago).

I have the following bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

TARGET_DIR=/usr/share/data

FILE_LIST=/home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-$now.txt

if [ -e $FILE_LIST ];
then
    rm -rf $FILE_LIST
fi

CMD="find $TARGET_DIR -regextype posix-extended -regex \".*/$now.*\" -fprint $FILE_LIST"

echo $CMD

findCmd=`$CMD`

if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    echo "command failed; $findCmd"
fi
```

The script runs fine but doesn't write anything to the file specified in the -fprint argument. If I take the command that is echo'd out and copy and paste it to cli, it works like I expect and my file has the list of files I want.

```
find /usr/share/data -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/20140624.*" -fprint /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt
```

I am guessing that there is something funky about the regex that gets interpreted incorrectly when running as a script but not as a command from the CLI. I've read in other threads about the need to enclose the asterisk in quotes, and I've tried the single tick and double tick, neither seem to work. I've also tried the back tick way of executing the command and the $() way, both yield the same result.

If I were getting any errors or messages this would be less perplexing. If anyone could look and see if I am doing something blatantly wrong, I'd appreciate the pointer!

If I run the command with bash -x, I get this output:

```
[user@data-provider bin]$ bash -x tgz2.sh
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ now=20140624
+ TARGET_DIR=/usr/share/data
+ FILE_LIST=/home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt
+ '[' -e /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt ']'
+ rm -rf /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt
+ CMD='find /usr/share/data -regextype posix-extended -regex '\''.*/20140624.*'\'' -fprint /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt'
+ echo find /usr/share/data -regextype posix-extended -regex ''\''.*/20140624.*'\''' -fprint /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt
find /usr/share/data -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/20140624.*' -fprint /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt
++ find /usr/share/data -regextype posix-extended -regex ''\''.*/20140624.*'\''' -fprint /home/user/txt-files/data-as-of-20140624.txt
+ findCmd=
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
```

Comment: I've tried it as me and with sudo. From the command line, as me, it works fine. When I run the script as me I get nothing; same result with sudo - no output.

Comment: Try this: `findCmd=$(eval "$CMD")`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that; now I get "no such file or directory". When I do an 'ls' as me on the dir I am searching and the dir I want to write to, they both exists and I can list them. I checked the ownership and permissions on the dirs and I own them and can write to them.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with `-fprint` since it should create the file regardless of whether or not anything is found.

Comment: @BroSlow - Maybe but it is creating the file, but it's empty. When I run it from the CLI, it works fine. I've done lots of scripts using find but with -name or -type and this has worked. It seems more related to the regex to me - but then again if I knew what I was doing we'd not be having this chat. ;-)

Comment: @Jon Does it work if you just write `find $TARGET_DIR -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/$now.*" -fprint $FILE_LIST` in the script?

Comment: You mean without the findCmd=$(...) or `...`? If so the answer is, no, it does not, which again, I find odd. Usually when I am off in the weeds Bash tells me so. Not in this case.

Comment: @Jon I mean replace the 3 lines `CMD=...; echo $CMD; findCMD=$(...)`, with just the above line.

Comment: @BroSlow - thanks, that is what I did and it still doesn't write the found files to the arg specified by -fprint.

Comment: @Jon What is the full command it's showing if you run it with `bash -x script`?

Comment: @BroSlow - I updated the description with that output.

Comment: @Jon Odd, it looks like it's running the `find` command twice, do you definitely have just `find $TARGET_DIR -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/$now.*" -fprint $FILE_LIST` in the script and no other instance of `find`?

Comment: @BroSlow - the script is the same as shown above; the file paths are slightly different but the construction of the command and the execution are as shown. When run from the script it completes much quicker than when run from the CLI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56243/discussion-between-broslow-and-jon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to just the below syntax in the script, without any variable assignment, fixed the issue.

```
find $TARGET_DIR -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/$now.*" -fprint $FILE_LIST
```

The problem with the original syntax, which I tested with

```
cmd="find -regex '.*/test.*' -fprint out.txt
$cmd
```

is that it gets run as

```
find -regex ''\''.*/test.*'\''' -fprint out.txt
```

but not entirely sure why variable substitution adds the erroneous single quotes.